# Best way to Implement a ListView

Tags: android, performance, listview

I have a simple question. my way is the best way to implement a listView? my List have about 80 items so performance is important. I know using ViewHolder is good for performance but I did it in true way? my code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_list, null, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        holder.location = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        holder.image = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.networkImageView);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.title.setText(eventList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.date.setText(eventList.get(position).getDate());
    holder.location.setText(eventList.get(position).getLocation());

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = ImageCacheManager.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    holder.image.setImageUrl(Constants.ImagesUrl + eventList.get(position).getIconFileName(), imageLoader);

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;
    public TextView date;
    public TextView location;
    public NetworkImageView image;
}
```

Comment: view holder pattern in 99% of cases is useless, it can be only a root of the bugs (see how many questions about view holder pattern here)

Comment: Honestly, if we're talking about what's "best", then I would (and do) go for `RecyclerView` over `ListView` every time. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28525112/android-recyclerview-vs-listview-with-viewholder)

Comment: One extra thing, here no need to check inflater is null or not, also no need to create inflater object.

Comment: @NigamPatro `also no need to create inflater object` there is a need, it is used in `inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_list, null, false);`

Comment: @pskink See my posted answer, you can do like that way also, so no need to create inflater object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since API 21, Android recyclerview implemented to improve the performance lists, with better preformance than ListView.

Show this: [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

Edit:

A suggestion, use Picasso Lib to load Async Images

Show this: [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: what is pros of Picasso front of Volley? I mention volley's networkImageView is very simple to use.

Comment: mainly, Picasso is more simple (1 call static) and no need to extend another class. In performance, I do not think there's much difference

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this line

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_list, null, false);
```

to

```
convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.event_list, null, false);
```

and no you can remove this line

```
 if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

from `getView()`.

Comment: the difference is you always call `LayoutInflater.from(context)` while OP calls it once. what is better in your opinion?

Comment: No need to create `Object` of `LayoutInflater`.

Comment: and please tell me what you do calling `LayoutInflater.from(context)` ?

Answer (score 0):

As @PPartisian mention a recyclerView can be considered as a better option.

But in your case (80 objects) a simple listview will do as most of the android phones has enough memory to load 80 objects.

There will be a trade of between a list view and a recyclerView or even other optimised methods.Each have there own pros and cons.

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33774215/optimized-list-view-with-1k-object-list).